# Carrierwave + RSpec testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I'm testing that my file uploads are correct with models with RSpec by setting `Model#filename = File.open(etc)`

When my specs run, all is grand. But the files still remain in my public/uploads directory after the testsuite finishes.

How do I get the files to delete on the end of running along with the records?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave/wiki/How-to:-Cleanup-after-your-Rspec-tests

Answer (score 0):

One way is to delete them at the end of a test using an instance method exposed by carrierwave. An example where your instance is `@user` and your carrierwave file attribute is `avatar` would be: `@user.remove_avatar!`